# Problem while configuring the file Delimeter("\t") in app.config(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

In my app.config file I made the setting like the following

```
<add key = "Delimeter" value ="\t"/>
```

Now while accessing the above from the program by using the below code

```
string delimeter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileDelimeter"].ToString();
StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
 streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

 Enumerable
.Range(0, outData.Length)
.ToList().ForEach(i => streamWriter.Write(outData[i].ToString() + delimiter));

streamWriter.WriteLine();
streamWriter.Flush();
```

I am getting the output as

```
18804\t20100326\t5.59975381254617\t
18804\t20100326\t1.82599797249479\t
```

But if I directly use `"\t"` in the **delimeter variable** I am getting the correct output

```
18804   20100326    5.59975381254617    
18804   20100326    1.82599797249479
```

I found that while I am specifying the "\t" in the config file, and while reading it into

the delimeter variable, it is becoming `"\\t"` which is the problem.

I even tried with    but with no luck.

I am using C#3.0.

Need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the XML entity that represents tab, which I believe is `&#09;` rather than the C# representation (which is `"\t"` as you already know).

```
<add key="Delimeter" value="&#09;"/>
```

Or you could always just take the easy way out:

```
// allow for <add key="Delimeter" value="\t"/>
if (delimiter == @"\t")
    delimiter = "\t";
```

Comment: Sir, your program works but my constraint is that since it is in app.config, so any user can modify that. "\t" is more user friendly as compared to the unicode version. Is there any other way of doing so?